# Are there any Samsung Artik libraries/header files for connecting to AWS IoT?

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, artik

I bought the Artik 053/055s modules to try and create an IoT project. Given that the Artik cloud and all other support is being removed, i am trying to connect the Artik to the AWS IoT service and use MQTT/HTTPS to push data to a DynamoDB instance.

I have tried looking for solutions to this on multiple sites including Samasung's Artik guides, forums etc., but I'm unable to find good resources/tutorials/samples for the same. If there are any resources for Artik<->AWS libraries or even sample codes it will be very helpful

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic in here. This is also not a code-writing service, so asking for code is also against the guidelines

Comment: Google "samsung artik aws client" yielded https://developer.artik.io/documentation/artik/cloud-services/aws/

Comment: Artik is dead - Samsung is shutting everything down by the end of this year.  Perhaps it's time to look at another platform.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @GambitSupport I will try this, it looks pretty extensive

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I wasn't aware of this. I'll remember not to in the future. Also, @stdunbar do you have any recommendations for platforms with a good support community?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do but I've used ESP32 based boards and they have [explicit support for AWS](https://github.com/espressif/esp-aws-iot) and Amazon has [good support too](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/freertos/latest/userguide/getting_started_espressif.html).  But there are many other boards too - it just depends on what you want to do.  You don't need to go to a full AWS IoT with just HTTPS -> API Gateway -> Lambda -> DynamoDB.

Comment: @stdunbar Yeah the ESP32 was one i was considering as well. Seems promising. I'll likely purchase one and start there. Thanks for the recommendations. I generally find it easier to learn from example so if you know about a sample project that implements the HTTPS -> ...... -> DynamoDB it'll help a lot. Thanks again :)